# Python Threading- "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am trying to implement threading in python 3.5 but is not working. While running the script, the process finishes with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

Here is the code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # divide training and testing data
    index70 = pd.read_csv('F:/dataset/rain_data/index70.csv', header=None)
    index70 = np.array(index70.values[0])
    # print(len(index70))
    # print(index70.values[0][5])

    # read netcdf
    netcdf_entire_dataset = Dataset("F:/dataset/entire_dataset.nc", "r")
    rain_models = netcdf_entire_dataset.variables['rain_models']

    data_table_t1 = np.zeros((101, 10))
    data_table_t5 = np.zeros((101, 10))
    data_table_t10 = np.zeros((101, 10))
    data_table_t20 = np.zeros((101, 10))
    data_table_t40 = np.zeros((101, 10))
    data_table_t80 = np.zeros((101, 10))

    threading.Thread(target=calculation, args=(0,)).start()
    threading.Thread(target=calculation, args=(6,)).start()
    threading.Thread(target=calculation, args=(12,)).start()
    threading.Thread(target=calculation, args=(18,)).start()

    np.savetxt('threshold_'+str(1)+'.csv', data_table_t1, delimiter=',', fmt='%10.5f')
    np.savetxt('threshold_' + str(5) + '.csv', data_table_t5, delimiter=',', fmt='%10.5f')
    np.savetxt('threshold_' + str(10) + '.csv', data_table_t10, delimiter=',', fmt='%10.5f')
    np.savetxt('threshold_' + str(20) + '.csv', data_table_t20, delimiter=',', fmt='%10.5f')
    np.savetxt('threshold_' + str(40) + '.csv', data_table_t40, delimiter=',', fmt='%10.5f')
    np.savetxt('threshold_' + str(80) + '.csv', data_table_t80, delimiter=',', fmt='%10.5f')
```

Calculation method has multiple nested for loops. The thread works for small example but, doesn't work for this method.

Output:
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: I am getting a similar problem on Python 3.7  Have you ever figured out what the issue here was?

Comment: @PCamargo  I am getting the same error. Did you got the solution???

Comment: @DeepakBhavsar, Every time I get these errors is because I either tried to access an object in memory that does not exist (assume an array has a certain size when it is actually smaller) or mix up the types I am working with.